# Does SQL Server evaluate functions once for every row?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, optimization

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT col1
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 
       BETWEEN col2 
       AND     col3
;
```

This gives a tooltip on the execution plan similar to this:

[image: Execution Tooltip]

Does the `dateadd` part of the seek predicates get executed for every row in the query? Or does SQL Server calculate the value once for the whole query?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Certain functions that are known to be [runtime constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/conor_cunningham_msft/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions) go through the process called [constant folding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175933%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). When 'folding' a constant, an expression is evaluated early in the query execution, the result is cached and the cached result used instead when needed. The expression in your query `DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()))` is, AFAIK, a runtime constant and thus will be folded and evaluated only once per query.

As trivia: the [`RAND()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx) function that one would expect to be unfoldable is actually foldable, which leads to some unexpected behavior. But others, for instance [`NEWID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx), are not foldable and will force an evaluation per row.

Comment: @StuartBlackler - [Here's a demonstration](https://gist.github.com/2822774) of how SQL Server folds functions like `GETDATE()`.

Answer (score 3):

Execution plans are great but sometimes they just don't tell you the truth.
So here is a proof based on performance test.

(and the bottom line - the expression is not being evaluated for every row)

---

```
;with t(i) as (select 0 union all select i+1 from t where i < 9)
select getdate()-1 as col1,getdate() as col2,getdate() as col3 
into #t 
from t t0,t t1,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5,t t6,t t7
```

> (100000000 row(s) affected)

This is the OP query and it takes around 12 seconds to run

```
SELECT col1
FROM   #t
WHERE  
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 
       BETWEEN col2 
       AND     col3
;
```

This query which stores the date in a parameter before the execution, takes about the same time, 12 seconds.

```
declare @dt datetime = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 

SELECT col1
FROM   #t
WHERE  
      @dt
       BETWEEN col2 
       AND     col3
;
```

And just to verify the results -
This query which does the computation on col1 and therefore have to recalculate the expression for every row takes about 30 seconds to run.

```
SELECT col1
FROM   #t
WHERE  
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, col1)) 
       BETWEEN col2 
       AND     col3
;
```

---

All queries were executed repeatedly showing about the same metrics